# Gmail notification remains on lock screen after email has been read/deleted on another device

Tags: google-pixel, android-11

I recently switch from iOS to Android (Google Pixel 4XL). One problem that I can't figure out:

- When I receive an email, I get a notification on my device's lock screen. Good.
- If I read (and/or delete) said email on another device, the above notification remains (until I unlock my phone)

Is this just a deficiency in Android vs iOS, or is something not working correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: The Google push notification system is not a "real-time system". For saving battery communication to/from Google is delayed so that lock screen messages may become outdated. Unlocking the device forces a refresh.

Comment: I agree with @Robert. Exclude Gmail from battery optimization, it may help

Comment: I just gave this a try. Unfortunately doesn't change anything... Are you both seeing the same behavior though? Thanks for the responses.